# Specifying a column value in an aggregate function vs using a WHERE clause

Tags: sql

I have a database `people` that looks like this:
[image]

I wanted to count the occurrences of `state='CA'`.

My first attempt was:

```
SELECT COUNT(state='CA')
FROM people 
;
```

this returned 1 row with a value of 1000. So I thought that there were 1000 people from CA in the database.

This turns out to be incorrect. I know that they are 127, which I can verify with the query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM people 
WHERE state='CA'
;
```

which returns 1 row with a value of 127.

I understand how the second query works. However, I do not understand what is wrong with the first one. What is it returning?

Comment: What RDBMS is this this?

Comment: count is not a sum  ..  your first query is improper because don't return the number of the rows  true  .. but the total number of rows  true or false

Comment: @OcasoProtal I use the DB browser for SQLite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

count is not a sum .. your first query is improper because don't return the number of the rows true .. but the total numbers  of not null rows true or false

if you want a filter count  you must use a where condition  (as your second query) otherwise you must use an if or a a select case inside the sum() function  eg:

```
 Select sum(case 
          when state='CA' then 1 else 0
           end) as my_result from People;
```

or if you want count  .. use null  and not 0min count

```
 Select count(case 
          when state='CA' then 1 else null
           end) as my_result from People;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see what's going on, run the query:

```
select state='CA' from people;
```

You will see that you will get one result for each row in people, with the value 0 or 1 (or True/False). What you've selected is whether state='CA' for each row, and there will be just as many of those results as there are rows.

You can't constrain a COUNT statement within the statement, you have to do that via the WHERE clause as in your second example.

Comment: What is the correct terminology of this - I'm trying to think of a better question name... Would `Constraining an aggregation in a where clause VS within the aggregate function body` be a good title?

Comment: No, because the second part doesn't make sense, you can't constrain it like that. You might want to ask "Why does COUNT(condition) not filter results" or something like that.

Comment: what would be a better way of referring to what is inside the aggregate function brackets? i.e. `count(<stuff>)`. Actually... is there anything else you can specify other than a column name? 

I guess that effectively `count(Person='X')` is really just specifying a column name and giving it a value for each row. 

I was kind of wondering if it were possible to equate aggregate functions with window functions. but I guess they are very different concepts? I.e... it would be incorrect to say that an aggregate functions IS a window function.

Comment: This is a link to a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51609719/what-is-correct-terminology-for-referring-to-aggregate-and-window-functions

Answer (score 1):

1st query will work if you use `case when` in side count, 
like below query will returned count of CA

```
SELECT sum( case when state='CA' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM people
```

Comment: apparently the 1st query works for him and returns 1000, clearly it is not sql server database

Answer (score 1):

Try this-:

```
Select count(case when state='CA' then 1 else null end) as xyz from People;
```

Answer (score 1):

In first query it is assigning the value 'CA' to the column state for all 1000 rows instead of filtering the values. That is what `SELECT` does. `SELECT` does not filter the number of returning rows, it modifies the data.

Whereas in `WHERE` clause the rows are being filtered first then the `SELECT` clause runs the `COUNT` function.

There is a sequence for running the query. It starts from `FROM` then `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` at the end `SELECT` will run.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the actual question - why do you get 1000? I'm guessing that there are 1000 rows in your database, or at least 1000 where state is not null. Count will return the number of rows where the thing inside the () is not null and as one of your comments says, the part inside your () will return either true or false, neither of which is null, so will count them all. Your second example is of course the right way to do it.

Comment: No,it (the part inside parentheses) will return true or false ***or unknown***, the latter of which is represented as a null value.

Comment: That's why I said there are 1000 rows where the state is not null. As you suggest if the state is null, the Count(state='CA') would not have counted it.